# How to determine git remote name by giving the repo URL?

Tags: git, shell, github, version-control, git-remote

I'm trying to get the remote name of the giving URL:

```
$ git ls-remote --get-url

git@github.com:foo/bar.git
```

```
$ git remote -v

origin  git@github.com:my-username/bar.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:my-username/bar.git (push)
upstream    git@github.com:foo/bar.git (fetch)
upstream    git@github.com:foo/bar.git (push)
```

Is there any way to find the remote name by giving a URL `git@github.com:foo/bar.git` to determine which remote it belongs to?

Comment: Note that in general, a remote can refer to multiple URLs and a there can be multiple remotes with the same URL.  Also note that there are multiple possible syntaxes for SSH URLs in Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this directly with git, but you could pipe the result into a grep and format it:

```bash
git remote -v | grep "git@github.com:foo/bar.git" | cut -f1 | head -1
```